# How to filter out all the entries with 0000:00:00 00:00 entries?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have created a table with a column that has the time stamp of all the entries. and it also allows my consumers to put date. But now due to some users who enter fake dates like

```
**2014:08:23 00:03**
**0000:05:22 12:34**
**2013:00:12 01:32**
```

so now how do I eliminate all the invalid entries and display only those have the valid date.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What is the column type?

Comment: i tried converting it into epoch and then matching but that again increased my complexity. I tried using strtotime and date() and time() also.

Comment: Whould you like to delete it from the database? Or only from the frontend visualisation?

Comment: @burhan..the column type is timestamp

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(date,%Y) !='0000'  use in your selecting query

Comment: @Jens its only for the front end visualization.

Comment: @anand what if the date comes like 2014:00:23. the year according to you will be valid. but the date is actually invalid.

Comment: two options are there, check year, month, date separately in your query  or add date time calender at front end